# Полый и полный

Tags: этимология

Однокоренные антонимы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это общеславянские слова, имеющие разные корни.

В латинском языке они имеют следующие соответствия: plere - наполнять и palum - открыто.

В русской языке слово "полый" родственно слову "поле" со значением "открытое пространство",а слово "полный" имеет в качестве родственников  плод и племя.

Comment: В латинском языке они имеют следующие соответствия: plere - наполнять

Хм... а по-французски plein air наоборот "открытый воздух"

Comment: Видимо, plein air означает не "открытый", а "полный" воздух... хотя логика французов не совсем ясна...

Comment: >Видимо, plein air означает не "открытый", а "полный" воздух...

Посмотрел в словарь. Да, именно так. Если дословно, то "полный". И 1-ое значение фран. слова *"plein"* - полный. Причём указано, что происходит от латинского *plenus* - полный.